# How does Composer know what MediaWiki extensions to load?

Tags: composer-php, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

We've switched from using Semantic Bundle to install extensions by using Composer. Now we can skip, for some extensions, manually including entry points at the LocalSettings.php file (http://www.bn2vs.com/blog/2013/11/24/introduction-to-composer-for-mediawiki-developers). But how does MediaWiki know which extensions to load. Does it read composer.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as stated in [www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Composer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Composer):

> Composer creates an autoloader at vendor/autoload.php, which is
>   included by WebStart.php

I verified this - `WebStart.php` simply does this:

```
# Load composer's autoloader if present
if ( is_readable( "$IP/vendor/autoload.php" ) ) {
    require_once "$IP/vendor/autoload.php";
}
```